# In stored procedure if null value found in column of table it should skip

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here I am trying to check if data column `Data_export` is null; if so, then my query should skip (data + @Data_separate) section otherwise it must be included.

I searched a lot, but that code is not working.

Here's my original code...

```
WITH a AS 
(
   SELECT 
       data + @Data_Separate AS data, 
       srno 
   FROM   
       Data_export WITH(nolock) 
   WHERE  
       srno > @FetchSrNo 
       AND srno <= @srno 
       AND segment_indicator = 1 
       AND Mem_code = @MemberCode                       
) 
SELECT 
    -- stuff(                       
    (SELECT a.data 
     FROM   a 
     ORDER  BY srno 
     FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)') 
     --,1,0,'') 
     AS data
```

Comment: How about using `COALESCE ( expression [ ,...n ] ) ` ?

Comment: can you elaborate this statement  *isnull function is not working here because i am taking data whose srno is greater than fetchsrno and less than srno.*

Comment: @VR46: Please ignore my that sentence. What i want is if data column in null then i dont want to select Data_Separate as well otherwise i will take both data as well as Data_Separate. Here i dont know how to check that condition in select statement. Please help

Comment: Can't you just add a `AND Data_Export IS NOT NULL` to your CTE? That would skip all rows where that column is null ...

Answer (score 0):

`Anything` + `NULL` = `NULL`. So

```
WITH a AS 
(
   SELECT 
       coalesce(data,'') + coalesce(@Data_Separate,'') AS data,  --or Isnull(@Data_Separate,'')
       srno 
   FROM   
       Data_export WITH(nolock) 
   WHERE  
       srno > @FetchSrNo 
       AND srno <= @srno 
       AND segment_indicator = 1 
       AND Mem_code = @MemberCode                       
) 
SELECT 
    -- stuff(                       
    (SELECT a.data 
     FROM   a 
     ORDER  BY srno 
     FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)') 
     --,1,0,'') 
     AS data
```